# OMNeT++ Simulating a project that references INET: 'cannot load library libINET.dll'

Tags: dll, omnet++, inet

I am trying to build and simulate a project that references INET (the INETWirelessTutorial actually), however I get the error below that says " Error: Cannot load library '../inet/src//libINET.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed". My project WireTryLiveson references project INET. I wonder if I need to link path environment variables differently? I tried the following:

1. Open "RSVPPacket.msg", modify it then change it back, and save it (which was suggested by a google group when I searched "libinet.dll")
2. Build INET

Neither seemed to work. INET Example projects simulate just fine.

What should I change so I can load libINET.dll?

[You can see the libINET.dll here on the Project Explorer on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCWWK.png)

[Here are my environment variables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JruB.png)

Here's what the OMNET++ Console displays with my error:

```
Starting...

$ cd C:/inetModule/WireTryLiveson
$ WireTryLiveson.exe -m -n .;../inet/src;../inet/examples;../inet/tutorials;../inet/showcases --image-path=../inet/images -l ../inet/src/INET omnetpp.ini

OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2017 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.1.1, build: 170508-adbabd0, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer


<!> Error: Cannot load library '../inet/src//libINET.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

End.

Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819
Working directory: C:/inetModule/WireTryLiveson
Command line: WireTryLiveson.exe -m -n .;../inet/src;../inet/examples;../inet/tutorials;../inet/showcases --image-path=../inet/images -l ../inet/src/INET omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
PATH=;C:/inetModule/inet/src;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;;C:/omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1.1/ide/jre/bin/server;C:/omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1.1/ide/jre/bin;C:/omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1.1/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1;
OMNETPP_ROOT=C:/omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.1.1/
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=C:\omnetpp-5.1.1-src-windows\omnetpp-5.1.1\images
```

Here's my omnetpp.ini:

```
[General]
network = WirelessTry
sim-time-limit = 25s
*.host*.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"
*.hostA.numUdpApps = 1
*.hostA.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
*.hostA.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "hostB"
*.hostA.udpApp[0].destPort = 5000
*.hostA.udpApp[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.hostA.udpApp[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.hostA.udpApp[0].packetName = "UDPData"
*.hostB.numUdpApps = 1
*.hostB.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPSink"
*.hostB.udpApp[0].localPort = 5000
*.host*.wlan[0].typename = "IdealWirelessNic"
*.host*.wlan[0].mac.useAck = false
*.host*.wlan[0].mac.fullDuplex = false
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 500m
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true
*.host*.**.bitrate = 1Mbps
```

Here's my file wirelessTry.ned:

```
import inet.common.figures.DelegateSignalConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
network WirelessTry
{
    parameters:
        string hostType = default("WirelessHost");
        string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");
        @display("bgb=650,500;bgg=100,1,grey95");
    @figure[title](type=label; pos=0,-1; anchor=sw; color=darkblue);
    @figure[rcvdPkText](type=indicatorText; pos=420,20; anchor=w; font=,20; textFormat="packets received: %g"; initialValue=0);
    @statistic[rcvdPk](source=hostB_rcvdPk; record=figure(count); targetFigure=rcvdPkText);
    @signal[hostB_rcvdPk];
    @delegatesignal[rcvdPk](source=hostB.udpApp[0].rcvdPk; target=hostB_rcvdPk);
submodules:
    visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
        @display("p=580,125");
    }
    configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        @display("p=580,200");
    }
    radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
        @display("p=580,275");
    }
    figureHelper: DelegateSignalConfigurator {
        @display("p=580,350");
    }
    hostA: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
        @display("p=50,325");
    }
    hostB: <hostType> like INetworkNode {
        @display("p=450,325");
    }
```

}

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all go to `INET` properties | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options...` | `Compile` tab | `More >>` and ensure that you have set "Export include path for other projects" and "Force compiling object files for use in DLLs". And in `Target` tab set "Export this shared/static library for other projects". Then rebuild `INET`.

If it doesn't help, then try the following workaround:

1. In properties of your project (e.g. `WireTryLiveson`):

   - select `inet` in `Project References`
   - go to `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options...` | `Target` and select "Shared library (.dll, .so or .dylib)"
   - go to `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options...` | `Compile` and select  "Add include paths exported from referenced projects"
2. In `Run` | `Run Configurations...` of your project select `opp_run` and ensure that `Working dir`  actually indicates the directory which contains `omnetpp.ini`.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy D! I run Windows 10. Setting "Force compiling object files for use in DLLs" in INET and targeting "Shared library" in WireTryLiveson's makemake got it to go! Thank you for your valuable insight.